# Wiping an SSD without ruining pre-installed OS?

Tags: ssd, windows-11, secure-erase

I bought a new ASUS laptop with an SSD and Windows 11 pre-installed. Unfortunately, the laptop has some issues and since consumer protection laws in my country allow you to return goods purchased from the internet within 14 days, that's what I'm planning to do. I'd like to wipe all my data securely before that, but the Windows installation needs to stay intact, as if I just performed a factory reset. How can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you use the Windows 11 install creator tool to make an install USB stick, to use after you have done a secure erase?

Comment: ASUS laptops usually have a System Recovery Partition, so all you really need to do is (securely) erase the main data partition, then, as documented in your user manual, you should be able to do a "ASUS Factory Reset", which should set your laptop to the condition it was when you first turned it on

Comment: https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1013064/

Comment: What Data you want to Erase ? (A) You can use file shredders to achieve that. (B) You can uninstall software. (C) You can delete Passwords & Wifi Connections using third Party tools. (D) You can make alternate Admin user , log in to that & remove the user with Erased Data. (E) Eventually , you can make a fake user , install unwanted software , copy over some Dummy Documents & then return that Machine !

Answer (score 2):

You may delete your own data from the disk and you may more strongly
reset Windows to factory format.

See the article
[How to Reset Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4130-reset-windows-10-a.html).

The procedure is :

- Run *Settings > Update & Security > Recovery*
- Under "Reset this PC" click "Get started"
- When prompted click "Remove everything".

Answer (score -2):

There are apps that does this but they were found to be flawed. The simplest and definite method is to find a large file and then copy it multiple time into the drive itself until the drive is full, then delete them all.